# User Registration form with JS JOBS Joomla extension

Tags: joomla2.5

I have successfully installed Js Jobs extension on my Joomla 2.5 project, but I can't select User Registration item (just can't find it) when creating a menu to allow a user to subscribe either as an employer or a job seeker. I can see the JS JOBS Register plugin among components installed, but no item referring to registration shows up when clicking on Select button while creating a menu or any other module. Check out my screenshots attached please. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately was able to resolve this issue by removing completely the other extension that was previously installed in the project, Joombah Jobs. Thanks